# Checking for Whitespaces in String

Tags: python, string

I wonder how to check for whitespaces in string. I know about `isspace()` method, which checks for any whitespace. But what about extra whitespace around string? For example:

```
def check_string(string):
    <...>
    return result

check_string(' The string has some whitespace.')
False

check_string(' Extra whitespace is not good. ')
False

check_string('This string is clean')
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way with [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)/[`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
def check_string(string):
    return not (string.startswith(' ') or string.endswith(' '))

check_string(' The string has some whitespace.')
# False

check_string(' Extra whitespace is not good. ')
# False

check_string('This string is clean')
# True
```

Or with a regex:

```
import re

def check_string(string):
    return bool(re.fullmatch('\S(.*\S)?', string))

check_string(' The string has some whitespace.')
# False

check_string(' Extra whitespace is not good. ')
# False

check_string('This string is clean')
#True
```

Answer (score 0):

The string.strip() function will remove both leading and trailing whitespace. Therefore:

```
def check_string(s):
  return len(s) == len(s.strip())
```